# Confused between structures and strucutre pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure

I wanted to know the difference between

```
struct file_operations {

} a;
```

and

```
struct file_operations {

} *a;
```

As in how are they allocated in memory? How does the compiler know about the memory location of 'a' in the first case? Is it from symbol table? If so how is address to symbol table(or any other table) found?

In the second case I'm assuming the memory address gets stored in a variable of size 32 bits , how is this variables location(address of 'a' in second code) figured out?

Comment: Never declare a structure that way, the fact that it's valid code doesn't mean that it's good.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, an instance of the structure is allocated in memory, the ammount of bytes allocated equals the value returned by `sizeof(a)`.

In the second case a pointer is allocated, the ammount of bytes allocated equals the size of a pointer i.e. `sizeof(void *)`.

As you might be guessing, the second case doesn't allow you to access the fields of the structure, becuase the memory the pointer points to, is invalid until you request enough memory from the heap, or until you make it point to an instance like the one in your first example.

Suppose that we had the following structure

```
struct Data {
    int    quantity;
    double value;
    char   name[100];
};
```

If you do the following

```
struct Data data;
```

then an instance of `struct Data` is allocated, you can access it's fields immediately, for example

```
data.quantity = 1;
data.value = 3.0;

strcpy(data.name, "My Name Is ...");
```

If you declare a pointer, like

```
struct Data *pointer;
```

then you can't access the fields until you make the pointer point to a valid instance of `struct Data`, otherwise undefined behavior will happen, you can create such instance by just taking the address of the `struct Data data;` that we already initialized above, like this

```
pointer = &data;
```

the lifetime of the pointee restricts the validity lifetime of the pointer, once you go out of the scope where `data` was declared, then the pointer will point to garbage, because `data` would have been deallocated.

Another way to make the pointer valid, is using `malloc()`, i.e. by requestion memory from the system heap, that is done by asking for  `sizeof(struct Data)` bytes, like here<sup>1</sup>

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
```

after that, you first check that memory was allocated, when there is a problem `malloc()` is guaranteed to return a special poitner `NULL`, it's an invalid poitner that helps you check if `poitner` is actually pointing to valid memory,

```
if (pointer != NULL) 
{
    pointer->quantity = 1;
    pointer->value = 3.0;

    strcpy(pointer->name, "My Name Is ...");
}
```

In this case the pointer is valid until you decide it isn't, when you do, you must call `free()` like this

```
free(pointer);
```

after that if you try to access the pointer again, undefined behavior will occur.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You can also make it independent of the type of `pointer` by using this syntax `pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));`, since `sizeof(*pointer)` is equal to `sizeof(struct Data)`.</sub>

Comment: I hope the explanation helps you understand, it's not easy to get used to these concepts, but once you do, you will start liking it, and in my case I started hating many other programming languages I was using by the time I got all this.

Answer (score 2):

> how are they allocated in memory?

In both cases, it depends on where the variable is defined.

At namespace scope (C++) or file scope (C), it's a global variable, with an address assigned when the program starts. Typically, that's specified by the symbol table, as you say.

At block scope, it's an automatic variable, and memory is typically allocated on the function's stack frame, some time before the program reaches the definition.

At class scope, it's part of the class that contains it.

> In the second case I'm assuming the memory address gets stored in a variable of size 32 bits

It's however large a pointer is. On a 32-bit platform, that will be 32 bits. In this case, there is no `file_operations` object, only a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements do two things: (1) Define a struct called `struct file_operations`, (2) Declare an uninitialized variable of that type.

The first allocates space the size of the struct on the stack (or in static storage, if outside a function.) Data members of the structure can then be accessed like `a.member1 = 1`. When inside a function, `a` is on the stack. It is just like any other variable declaration, for example `int a`. If outside a function, it declares a global variable. Its member address can be found using `&a`. The compiler uses a symbol table while compiling that indicates the type, relative address, etc of each token.

When declaring a global variable and compiling into a library, it also generates a symbol in the binary's symbol table so that it can be linked by the linker.

The second case declares a pointer to a `struct file_operations`. A pointer is a variable holding a member address, so it has a size of 4 byte in your case. Its type is `struct file_operations *` which indicates that the data it points to must be of type `struct file_operations`. The variable here is unintialized. The pointer does not contain a valid address, and dereferencing it would fail. To use it:

```
struct file_operations a;
struct file_operations* pa = &a;
```

Would make `pa` point to `a`. Then `a`'s members can be access through `pa` via `pa->member1 = 1`. The address of the pointer itself `&pa` is also on the stack (or in static memory when outside a function). `&pa` is the address of the pointer, aka a pointer to a pointer. `pa` is the address that the pointer points to.